# ListFragment onListItemClick not called, only CustomAdapter does the job

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

Title self-explanatory. I have gone through many questions about `onListItemClick` not being called in a `ListFragment` and I have found out that none of the answers works for me.

I have tried to use the `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in my item xml, I have tried to manually implement the `setOnItemClickListener` but none have worked so far.

The only trick that listens to the item click is to manually set the listener in my Custom Adapter, but I want to use the `onListItemClick` since this is what is intended for. Please find the code below and I would appreciate if you can spot why `onListItemClick` is not being called.

**ListFragment**

```
public class BrowseFragment extends ListFragment {

    final String TAG = "BrowseFragment";
    private ArrayList<Event> mEvents = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListView mList;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    private EventListArrayAdapter mAdapter;

    public BrowseFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_browse, container, false);
        mList = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.pullToRefresh);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                refreshContent();
            }
        });

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return v;
    }

    private void refreshContent() {
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("events").get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            mEvents.clear();
                            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                                mEvents.add(document.toObject(Event.class));
                            }
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Failure", e);
//                        loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (mEvents.isEmpty()) {
            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("events").get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                                    mEvents.add(document.toObject(Event.class));
                                }
                                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Failure", e);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mAdapter = new EventListArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), mEvents);
        new EventListArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), mEvents);
        mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_serach, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    // CODE BELOW IS NOT TRIGGERED

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item " + pos + " was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**CustomAdaper**

```
public class EventListArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Event> {

    private final ArrayList<Event> mList;
    private final Activity context;

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView title;
        protected ImageView cat_pic;
    }

    public EventListArrayAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Event> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_event_row, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.mList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_event_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.cat_pic = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.category_img);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(mList.get(position).getTitle());
        Map<String, Boolean> cats = mList.get(position).getCategory();
        String cat_keyval = cats.keySet().iterator().next();
        holder.cat_pic.setImageResource(MyUtilFunctions.categoryIcons(cat_keyval));

// ******* THE CODE BELOW TRIGGERS THE CLICK BUT I WANT TO SET THIS IN MY LISTFRAGMENT **************

//        row.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener(){
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                Log.v("text", "Title clicked " + mList.get(position).getEvent_id());
//                Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, EventInfoActivity.class);
//                myIntent.putExtra("EVENT_ID", mList.get(position).getEvent_id());
//                context.startActivity(myIntent);
//
//            }
//        });

        return row;
    }

}
```

**Fragment XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.hobbypop.Fragments.BrowseFragment">
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/pullToRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:dividerHeight="10.0dp">
        </ListView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Item XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_3"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:elevation="5dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/category_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_category"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Title"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/category_img"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/category_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i know this should not work ....but still did you try block descendents to your relative layout instead of the linear layout... (item) or using it in both of the layouts.. ??

Comment: Yup, no luck. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: try this too `if(child != null && !child.hasFocusable() && inList) {
//click logic
}`I changed my child views to clickable = false and focusable = false and it work for me.

Comment: the if in itemClick and the later in the layout..

Comment: the `if` in the `onListItemClick` you mean? Or what do you mean in `itemClick`?

Comment: yes onItemClick i mean..

Comment: Why the downvote? Please provide feedback if you downvote otherwise it does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that has worked for me to trigger `onListItemClick` and that I have not read anywhere yet has been to set `getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)` on the `onActivityCreated` method of the `ListFragment`.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mAdapter = new EventListArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), mEvents);
    new EventListArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), mEvents);
    mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
}
```

There is not need to use the `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`
 in the item xml with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading data to a [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html), you don't have to use a [ListFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) (However it will work even if you use). To handle ListView item clicks, set an [OnItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) to the listview using setOnItemClickListener().

Comment: And what class should I use for this purpose? I thought a ListFragment was just for this.

Comment: Btw, I tried the `OnItemClickListener` and it does not work. Where would this be included? In the `onViewCreated` method of the `ListFragment`?

Comment: ListFragment  is like dedicated for lists. If using it has its own methods like onListItemClicked(). In that case you dont have to use a ListView. ListView item clicks are handled via OnItemClickListener. In short, You can use a normal Fragment along with a listview and handle the clicks using OnItemClickListener

Comment: In onViewCreated, add this mList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {}) and implement the method